# Self-written vscode extension cannot contribute a new notebook type which uses the jupyter notebook format

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm writing my own vs-code-extension which will contribute a **custom notebook** type to vs-code.

As described in vscode's official [notebook extension guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/notebook#example), I want to use the [jupyter notebook format](https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format_description.html) - because of its powerful language selection and code execution capabilites -, but write my own serializer for it. I also want to write a custom controller and markdown renderer.

Following the instructions on the doc page, I wrote a simple extension which contributes the provided example serializer code. On the doc page, opening a custom notebook is supposed to look like [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/api/extension-guides/notebook/ipynb-simple-provider.png).

But I have no idea, how to *"try running your extension and opening a Jupyter Notebook formatted file saved with the .notebook extension"*; when I run the extension and open a custom notebook, I can neither execute code cells (no run buttons anywhere) nor are any kernels recognized.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.